# FeatherPad limited encodings

Tags: text-editor, 20.10, encoding

I am testing the ***FeatherPad*** simple text editor. Ubuntu 20.10 provides version 0.12.1 of FeatherPad. On this version, I noticed that only a limited variety of text encodings are supported. Especially important for my usage are the Latin-5 (Turkish) **ISO-8859-9** and/or **CP1254** and the Latin-Greek **ISO-8859-7** and/or **Windows-1253** encodings.

Is there a configuration method to add support for these in *FeatherPad*?

Do the newer versions of *FeatherPad* support any of the above-mentioned encodings. Comments from users of the newer versions of *FeatherPad* will be helpful.

Comment: Later versions are available as *snaps* I see, ie. https://snapcraft.io/featherpad [*unofficial sorry*] so you could given them a *spin* (without touching your current packaged version). 15.0 is *stable* & 16.0 is *edge* as snaps..   Sorry I only use english so haven't explored further, and hadn't noticed our packaged version was so behind, so thanks there.  If you find a postive result, a bug report asking for later packaged version maybe warranted.

Comment: Personally I hate snaps and there are huge: Version 0.15.0 is 98MB and 0.16.0 is 103MB. Can anybody that has already tried these versions comment?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @KGIII The version of Ubuntu and FeatherPad was already specified in the question.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli My bad. That was way back before I had coffee. Anyhow, I don't know if it has Turkish support, but it's pretty trivial to build it and install it yourself from source. It's got directions [here](https://github.com/tsujan/FeatherPad/blob/master/INSTALL) if you want to build it. I was able to build it with nary a problem on 18.04, an older Qt library to deal with, once I got the dependencies sorted out.

Comment: I had to switch to https://notepadqq.com/s/